# How to combine arrays into array of arrays?

Tags: javascript

So, I have this 2 arrays:

```
var num = [1, 2, 3];
var letters = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
```

I need to combine it to something like this:

```
var result = [[1, 'a', 'numberandletters'],[2, 'b', 'numberandletters'],[3, 'c', 'numberandletters']]
```

The third element inside the array is constant when it is being filled. My code so far is this:

```
for (var x=0; x=3; x++)
     result[x] = [num[x], letters[x], 'numberandletters']
```

But I need to execute it without looping statement.
Is there any function or something I can use to combine these arrays?

Comment: `without looping` *Any* construct that achieves your desired output will use a loop somewhere, even if abstracted behind a method like `.map` (unless the `num` and `letters` are guaranteed to contain a static number of elements, but writing such code would be WET and silly)

Comment: *"But I need to execute it without looping"*... just out of curiosity: **why**?

Comment: The way to do this would be with map function but then again even that uses loop

Comment: Yes there might many functions to achieve your desire output but all those function uses loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var num = [1, 2, 3];
var letters = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

num.map((n,i) => Array(n, letters[i], 'nummberAndLetters'))
```

Output: As you expected.

If you want it as a function then,

```
function getCombinedArray(num, letter) {
    return num.map((n,i) => Array(n, letters[i], 'nummberAndLetters'));
}

getCombinedArray(num, letters);
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay. This is what it will be when you don't want to use loop.

```js
const num = [1, 2, 3]
const letters = ['a', 'b', 'c']
let result = [
  [
    num[0],
    letters[0],
    'numberandletters'
  ],
  [
    num[1],
    letters[1],
    'numberAndLetter'
  ],
  [
    num[2],
    letters[2],
    'numberAndLetter'
  ]
]
console.log(result)
```

Comment: I had the same idea but didn't answer it as it won't do justice. After all, this is SO not 9gag... ;-)